# Extremely simeple SignalR Client to updating XMAL UI

Tags: xamarin.forms, signalr, signalr.client

im trying to get the most basic part of signalR working from PCL, send a message, and then recieve the message back from the hub and update a label.
Everything from the hub side of things is working perfect, when i send a message from an Entry and debug i can see the newly entered message come back from the hub.

The strange thing is that i need to push the send button twice before the label is updated for the first message send, then any other send does not update the label but the newly entered send message does come back from the Hub at the MessageRecieved Part. The Label never updates. Any Ideas??.

As the end solution will not be crazy complex i havnt gone down the path of using a viewmodel. I've updated labels from the code behind plenty of times after a http response.

Here is my code

```
private HubConnection Connection = new HubConnection("http://*******");
private IHubProxy ChatHubProxy;

public RealTime()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     ChatHubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("SynapseVerificationHub");

     Connection.Start();

     ChatHubProxy.On("MessageReceived", (string username, string text) =>
     {

     RecievedTxt.Text = text;

     });

 }

 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ChatHubProxy.Invoke("SendMessage", "Kosta", KostaMessageTxt.Text);
 }
```

Comment: Try to update the label on UI thread

Comment: Hay, thankyou @YuriS for that, worked perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the event handler runs on a different thread, you need to update your UI from the UI thread to make it have effect immediately.

Change your code to this:

```
ChatHubProxy.On("MessageReceived", (string username, string text) =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        RecievedTxt.Text = text;
    });

});
```